# Remove auto trigger from ECR as Source in AWS CodePipeline

Tags: devops, aws-codepipeline, amazon-ecr

I have a pipeline with `Source` stage which reads from ECR. For every image pushed to ECR my pipeline is triggered automatically. I don't want this behavior and would like to start my pipeline manually from `Release Change` button. How to achieve this?

I managed to achieve the same for GitHub Source Stage by removing the webhook from GitHub repo itself. Unable to find similar web-hook for ECR.

Answer (score 0):

CodePipeline uses CloudWatch rules when the source is configured as ECR to start its execution on an Image Push.

To verify this, you can check the associated CloudWatch rule [1] and look if the event pattern currently set on your rule matches an event on ECR Image Push. Also you can refer to this sample Event for a Completed Image Push [2] to see the available attributes for filtering.

As a general guidance, you might want to check the following links that will walk through the process of using ECR as a Source on CodePipeline[3].

[1] Use CloudWatch Events to Start a Pipeline (Amazon ECR Source)  - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/create-cwe-ecr-source.html

[2] Amazon ECR Events and EventBridge - Sample Events from Amazon ECR - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/ecr-eventbridge.html#ecr-eventbridge-bus

[3] AWS DevOps Blog - https://aws.amazon.com/pt/blogs/devops/build-a-continuous-delivery-pipeline-for-your-container-images-with-amazon-ecr-as-source/